# Cosmos DB (NO SQL API) - ordering by Index_of

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I want to search some string in my column and i want to return the data in the order of index where they are found. Something like this:

***SELECT c.myData INDEX_OF(c.myData , "ABC") AS Ordered FROM c
WHERE INDEX_OF(c.searchablePartNum, "ABC") >= 0
ORDER BY c.Ordered``***`

This returns the result but it does not sort the result based on the output of the INDEX_OF, what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

**ORDER BY** is applicable only on property or expression. In the query it is applied on `Ordered` which is computed at runtime only. Therefore create computed property using `.NET SDK V3` or `Java SDK V4` and apply order by on that computed property only.

Below is the computed property:

```js
{
  "name": "abcIndex", 
  "query": SELECT VALUE INDEX_OF(c.searchablePartNum, "ABC") FROM c
}
```

Before you can **ORDER BY** `abcIndex` you must add it to your indexing policy. After your indexing policy is updated, you can order by the computed property.

```sql
SELECT * FROM c ORDER BY c.abcIndex
```

For more information on ORDER BY refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/order-by).